# Rapid inserts using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm developing a data logging application that will be writing a row to a SQLite database roughly every 100ms. Without using transactions, inserting 100 rows at this interval takes 20 seconds - twice as long as it should.

Does SQLite provide anything that can help with what I'm trying to do, or is it a case of rolling my own solution (e.g. committing a transaction every N rows or N seconds)?

Comment: I had the same requirements once and ended up with the "commit a transaction every N seconds" approach.

Answer (score 1):

Commit a transaction only when no new data value is yet available; otherwise, write the new value(s) in the same transaction.

This automatically throttles transactions to the largest sustainable rate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered 'Naive Inserts`?

http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/